# multi pipenv cross microserivces python

Tags: dockerfile, microservices, pipenv

I have a project which was decomposed into 3 different microservices, let's call then A, B, and C.

Each of services A and B holds their own Pipfile and Dockerfile (and the corresponding pipfile.lock).
For example:

**Service A** Pipfile:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[packages]
pandas= "*"
nltk = "*"
```

**Service B** Pipfile:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[packages]
pandas= "*"
tensorflow= "*"
```

and in each one of the **separate** Dockerfile (one for A and one for B) we deploy using :

```
RUN pipenv install --deploy --system --ignore-pipfile
```

Now, service C use both of the services code (A,B) so it's holds only Dockerfile which contains the lines:

```
WORKDIR ./A/
RUN pipenv install --deploy --system --ignore-pipfile
WORKDIR ./B/
RUN pipenv install --deploy --system --ignore-pipfile
```

Which install dependencies from the two services.

However, that architecture seems to be wrong as `pandas` package version must be the same as they meet in C and there are a lot of packages like `Pandas` in real life.

One solution I thought about it's to specify `pandas` version and then each of the Pipfile, but then why should I write it twice? it against any coder instinct I have.

Other solution, is to create Pipfile for C which will contain the joined dependencies (`pandas`) and in both of A and B Dockerfile deploy the corresponding Pipfile.lock and C Pipfile.lock, but that means that during development pipenv need to know two Pipfile and Pipfile.lock which is not supported.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I'm running into the same scenario

Comment: @room13 sadly, no.

Comment: :( did you find any other alternative? Any tool or hack?

Comment: From my experience, you should always use version number (locked major and minor, bug number can change) not star. This can cause issues after time just running `pipenv install`. So all projects should have exact versions defined in pipfile, even the C project. Next, I would ask, why do you have multiple projects in one container?